# how do I rotate and scale simultaneously on same UIImageView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiimageview

What I'm trying to accomplish is an settings gear in my Iphone game that is pulsing and rotating at the same time. Down below you can see my scale animation code. I tried multiple ways to rotate and scale at the same time, but what happens is that the other animation stops when i commit a new one.
How do I fix this problem?

```
   tt = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.01, 1.01);
    CGPoint center2 = gear.center;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.66666666666667/4
                     animations:^{

                        gear.center = center2;
                         gear.transform = tt;

                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                         [self method2];

                     }];
```

Comment: Maybe you could animate the bounds of the image view?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to set the transform with both rotate and scale transform instead of multiple animations?

```
CGAffineTransform tt= CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.01, 1.01);
tt= CGAffineTransformRotate(tt, radians);
CGPoint center2 = gear.center;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.66666666666667/4
                 animations:^{

                    gear.center = center2;
                     gear.transform = tt;

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                     [self method2];

                 }];
```

Answer (score 1):

you can using concatenating to do simultaneously rotate, scale and translate. In this scenario, you need move the anchor which is gear center to origin, then do scale and rotate, then move gear center back. **do not use tt = tt.xxxedBy()**

```
let anchor = gear.center
var tt = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -anchor.x, y: -anchor.y)
tt = tt.concatenating(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: radians))
tt = tt.concatenating(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.01, y:1.01))
tt = tt.concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: anchor.x, y: anchor.y))
// do animation ...
```

https://medium.com/@chenkaiphy/simultaneously-rotate-scale-and-translate-using-cgaffinetransfrom-f5ad00198adb

Comment: This finally helped me figuring out how to handle multiple transformations simultaneously!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the delegate for your gestures and we have a method that enables simultaneously gestures (pan, rotate, scale gestures)

```
yourGesture.delegate = UIGestureRecognizerDelegate


public func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```